# Angular - stop scroll snapping to the top on subscription timer

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a self updating list of orders that is scrollable. This is the parent component, where list is updated on a timer of 2 minutes, setup like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.internalError = false;
    this.subscription = timer(0, 120 * 1000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable()),
        filter(preferences => !!preferences), // emit only if `preferences` is defined and truthy
        tap(() => {
            this.isDeliverySlotsActive = this.shopService.isDeliverySlotsActive();
        }),
        switchMap(() => 
            forkJoin([
                    this.getInitialPendingOrders(true), 
                    this.getInitialPendingOrders(false),
                    this.getInitialDeliveredOrders(true),
                    this.getInitialDeliveredOrders(false),
                    this.getInitialCancelledOrders(true),
                    this.getInitialCancelledOrders(false)
                ]
            )
        )
      ).subscribe(res => {
            /* pending slots */
            this.loadedPendingSlotsOrders = [...res[0]["results"]];
            this.pendingSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedPendingSlotsOrders, true);
            /* pending no slots */
            this.loadedPendingNoSlotsOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(res[1]["results"], OrderStatus.PENDING, false);
            this.loadedProcessedNoSlotsOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(res[1]["results"], OrderStatus.PROCESSED, false);
            this.loadedPendingNoSlotsOrders = [...this.loadedPendingNoSlotsOrders, ...this.loadedProcessedNoSlotsOrders];
            this.pendingNoSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedPendingNoSlotsOrders, false);
            /* delivered slots */
            this.loadedDeliveredSlotsOrders = [...res[2]["results"]];
            this.deliveredSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedDeliveredSlotsOrders, true);
            /* delivered no slots */
            this.loadedDeliveredNoSlotsOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(res[3]["results"], OrderStatus.DELIVERED, false);
            this.deliveredNoSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedDeliveredNoSlotsOrders, false);
            /* cancelled slots*/
            this.loadedCancelledSlotsOrders = [...res[4]["results"]];
            this.cancelledSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedCancelledSlotsOrders, true);
            /* cancelled no slots */
            this.loadedCancelledNoSlotsOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(res[5]["results"], OrderStatus.CANCELLED, false);
            this.cancelledNoSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedCancelledNoSlotsOrders, false);
            /* data is ready, we can stop showing spinner */
            this.isLoaded = Promise.resolve(true);
    });
}

getInitialPendingOrders(hasSlots: boolean){
    return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING&status=FULFILLED" + (hasSlots ? "&only_slots=true" : ''));
}

getInitialDeliveredOrders(hasSlots: boolean){
    return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=DELIVERED" + (hasSlots ? "&only_slots=true" : ''));
}

getInitialCancelledOrders(hasSlots: boolean){
    return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=CANCELLED" + (hasSlots ? "&only_slots=true" : ''));
}
```

Furthermore, the component tree is as follows:

```
OrdersComponent (prepare data to send to children) -> OrdersListComponent (*ngFor of sections) -> OrdersListSectionComponent (*ngFor of orders) -> OrdersListItemComponent (single order)
```

Here you can see how the list looks (it's an inner scrollable div):

[image]

The css of the scrollable div:

```
.scrollable {
    min-height: 10vh;
    max-height: 50vh; 
    overflow: auto;
    background: 
        linear-gradient(white 33%, rgba(179,86,216, 0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(179,86,216, 0), white 66%) 0 100%,
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(34,34,34, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(34,34,34, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
    background-size: 100% 1.5rem, 100% 1.5rem, 100% 0.5rem, 100% 0.5rem;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

The template for the `OrdersListSectionComponent`:

```
<div *ngFor="let order of sectionOrders">
    <app-orders-list-item
        [order]="order"
        [timeline]="timeline"
    ></app-orders-list-item>
    <hr class="order-divider"/>
</div>
```

I have reached a situation where the scroll of this list snaps to the top when the timer is triggered. This is bad because if a user is scrolling through the list, the scroll shouldn't go back to the top.

Does anyone know how I could stop this unwanted scroll behaviour?

Comment: if you using ngFor to iterate items then try to add trackBy function

Comment: @Chellappanவ Please explain how this would solve my problem...

Comment: It will not recreate already rendered item. so using trackby may solve the issue. Have you tried it?

Comment: Not working unfortunately.

Comment: First off, you are subscribing a gazillion times - subscribe within subscribe. This is an antipattern, also because you lose control over what is going on. After `filter()` you should insert `switchMap(() => this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable())` and remove the inner subscription. I recommend that you adopt this pattern. Lastly, we don't know what is inside `getOrders` so it is difficult to know what causes snapping back to top.

Comment: @user776686 Updated.

Comment: I honestly don't think this code would be the root cause.  I have created a simple stackblitz, stubbing all the methods and api calls, forcing vertical scroll. The snap behavior is not there. All I can recommend is standard debugging: try bisecting your code, isolating methods. Also, doesn't your remaining code contain some sort of `window.location.reload()` somewhere?

Comment: This is quite the annoyance. No `window.location.reload()` to be found either. Could it be some property in my scrollable div? I'll update the question.

Comment: I did also notice that if I remove the scroll of this inner div, the main body scroll does not snap back to the top once the list is refreshed. This is only happening with this inner div scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `element.scrollTop` to save the position of the scrollbar and then use the saved value to set the scrollTop property to where it was when the timed function is called.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop?retiredLocale=it - https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/get-and-set-scroll-position-of-an-element/)

Comment: A variation of this approach worked for me. I tracked the position of the scroll and used the `filter()` operator in the timer subscription to filter out emissions if the scroll position was not the starting one.

Answer (score -1):

Subscribe to your timer, and onscroll reset your timer, something like:

```
timer = timer(0, 120 * 1000);
timersubscription: Subscription;

initializeTimer(): void { {
    this.timersubscription = this.timer.subscribe(() => console.log("Timer triggered");
}

refreshTimer(): void {
    this.timersubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.initializeTimer();
}

<div (scroll)="refreshTimer()"></div>
```

Comment: The act of re-subscribing is itself snapping the scroll to the top.